# Apply kubernetes configuration from kube-system namespace

Tags: kubernetes

I have kubernetes cluster which I created with [kops](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops) on AWS. I'm trying to use [kube-applier](https://github.com/box/kube-applier) to apply `yaml` configuration to my cluster: I created a deployment with `kube-applier`:

```
apiVersion: "extensions/v1beta1"
kind: "Deployment"
metadata:
  name: "kube-applier"
  namespace: "kube-system"
spec:
  # spec
```

and started it in `kube-system` namespaces as suggested in a README:
`kubectl --namespace=kube-system apply -f deployment.yaml`.

But then `kube-applier` fails with this error when received new file to apply:

```
$ kubectl apply -f /git/deployment.yaml
Error from server (Forbidden): error when retrieving current configuration of:
&{0xc43034ca91 0xc43034ca91 kube-system kube-applier /git/applier-deployment.yaml 0xc421432531  false}
from server for: "/git/deployment.yaml": deployments.extensions "kube-applier" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default" cannot get deployments.extensions in the namespace "kube-system"
```

How can I grant permissions to `kube-applier` pod to apply configurations in other namespaces?

Kubernetes version: `Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"9", GitVersion:"v1.9.6", GitCommit:"9f8ebd171479bec0ada837d7ee641dec2f8c6dd1", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-03-21T15:13:31Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}`

Comment: does this run in a CI build? It seems like you don't have the right access to talk to the k8s API probably missing `kubeconfig` file

Comment: @jhernandez  `kube-applier` is running in my cluster ("kube-system" namespace) and is watching for changes in git repository, if something changed in this repo it try to apply these files (and fails with error)

Comment: if you have RBAC enabled which it seems so. you should check the service account assigned to the pods .  It seems like the service account being used doesn't have a RoleBinding with the necessary permissions 
 see https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/

Comment: What is your Kubernetes version?

Comment: @Const version is `1.9`

Comment: Did you try with ‘apiVersion: apps/v1’ since I believe that extensions/v1beta1 is for 1.8 and lower. Can you give it a try and let me know?

Comment: @Const thanks, I tried, but with same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I grant permissions to kube-applier pod to apply configurations in other namespaces?

Create, or find, a `ClusterRole` with the correct resource permissions, then bind the `ServiceAccount` to it using a `ClusterRoleBinding` like so

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
    # C.R.B. don't have a "namespace:"
    name: my-kube-applier
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: default
  namespace: kube-system
```

**BUT**, as @jhernandez said, you will really want to create a dedicated `ServiceAccount` for `kube-applier` instead of granting what I presume is a very, very privileged `ClusterRole` to the `default` S.A. (which is what I did in the *example* above, but you should not do for real)

Creating a new `ServiceAccount` is super cheap: `kubectl -n kube-system create sa kube-applier` and then replace `name: default` with `name: kube-applier` in the `subjects:` block above.

Ideally one would create a customized least-privilege `ClusterRole` rather than using a massive hammer like `cluster-admin`, but generating the *correct* one would take some serious typing, so I'll leave that to your discretion.

Comment: Thanks! I created new `ServiceAccount` for `kube-applier` deployment with `RoleBinding` and it's working.